# Ajax Return success result with 403

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, http-status-code-403

Recently i call ajax for got some data, i have receive correct data from controller and success status. but its also return 403 error code i dont know whats problem with my code.

```
jQuery.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: url,
                                async: false,
                                dataType: 'json',
                                data: {id:pid,qty:qty,form_key:formKey} , 
                                success: function(data)
                                    {
                                        if(data.status == 'SUCCESS'){
                                            jQuery('#iwd_opc_top_review').html(data.review);
                                        }
                                    }
                            });
```

When click call ajax 1st time call success with no error code but next time its call success with 403 error code.

[image]

Comment: Your image doesn't show a 403 error code?

Comment: thanks for reply @DarrenSweeney Please check updated question

Comment: They are different URLs? Have you really looked at this?

Comment: Url are correct and response also correct but i dont know why got 403